# My HTML data is not showing in the database

Tags: php, sql, database

I've been trying to get my HTML form to submit to the specified database. I have tried everything I know still no result I can't seem to get the error.

HTML FORM

```
    <form action = "connect.php" method = "post">
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>

        <h5 style ="color:White;" style="font-family:verdana" align = "center"><font size = "2">

        <fieldset >
            <legend>Personal information:</legend>
            First name: <br>
            <input type = "text" name ="firstname">
            <br>
            Last name: <br>
            <input type = "text" name ="lastname"><br>
            Username: <br>
            <input type = "text" name = "username"><br>
            Password <br>
            <input type = "password" name ="password"><br>
            School <br>
            <input type = "text" name ="school"><br>
            Department <br>
            <input type = "text" name ="department"><br>
            Year Of Study <br>
            <input type = "text" name ="studyYear"><br>
            Email <br>
            <input type = "text" name ="email"><br>
            Phone number <br>
            <input type = "text" name ="phoneNumber"><br><br>
            Gender <br>
            <input type = "radio" name = "gender" value ="male">Male<br>
            <input type = "radio" name = "gender" value ="female">Female<br>
            <input type = "radio" name = "gender" value ="male">Other<br>
            <br><br>
            <input type ="submit" value ="Insert">
            </h5>
        </fieldset>
    </h5>
    </form>

PHP CODE

<?php
// Connect to localhost
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'sigma');

if(!$connect) {
    echo("Didn\'t work ". mysqli_error());
}

// Get values from the form
$ID = $_POST['UserID'];
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$school = $_POST['school'];
$dept = $_POST['department'];
$studyYear = $_POST['studyYear'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phoneNumber'];

// SQL query to insert the data collected from the form into the database.
$sql = mysqli_query ($connect, 'INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, username, password, 
    school, department, studyYear, email, phoneNumber) 
VALUES ("'.$firstname.'", "'.$lastname.'", "'.$username.'","'.$password.'",
 "'.$school.'", "'.$dept.'", "'.$studyYear.'", "'.$email.'", '.$phone.')');


if ($sql)
{
echo 'Inserted';

}

else
{
echo 'Not Inserted';
}



mysqli_close($connect);

?>
```

Comment: please add your PHP code.

Comment: What error/errors are you getting? Are you sure PHP errors are enabled??

Comment: @ShudhanshShekhar its below the HTML form code right beneath </form> thank you so much

Comment: @VSG24 No mysqli error message is displayed

Comment: may i know your error !

Comment: First, you can echo out your query and check it for errors. Additionally, I recommend using prepared statements for this sort of stuff - you're using mysqli already so it's not much more work.

Comment: please put `or die(mysql_error())` for every msqli function to detect the error.

Comment: @Aseem He said in his question "I can't seem to get the error". Also no need for ! in that case. A question mark would be more appropriate.

Comment: @VSG24 Please how do enable PHP errors?

Comment: I see you are connecting to the database with the root user and no password. Usually root isn't allowed to connect to the database on localhost. You are better off creating a user with it's own password and connect with that user/pass instead of root.

Comment: What kind of server are you running? XAMP on windows, Linux with Apache? You can try using a command prompt or console and going into the directory where your script is located and typing "php -l script.php" where script.php is the file name of your php script. That will tell if you have syntax errors in your code. If you are on a linux machine, try going to a console/terminal and typing "mysql -uroot -p" and press ENTER for the password when prompted. That will tell you if you can connect to localhost with the root user.

Comment: @pogeybait i'm using Wamp on windows

Comment: Thank you so much everyone for your help the mistake was from me, I was inputting a larger value than expected for my phone number field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should work for you, it's almost like Shudhansh but I wrapped the INSERT query in double-quotes and removed the concatenations between each variable and wrapped them each in their own single-quotes:

```
$sql = mysqli_query ($connect,
"INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, username, password,
school, department, studyYear, email, phoneNumber) 
VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$username', '$password', '$school', '$dept', '$studyYear', '$email', '$phone')");
```

I ran it on my local machine and it worked.

Also your connect.php is trying to grab a $_POST['userID']' from the request but you don't pass it from the form so that'll stop it all together, you should just create an auto-incrementing ID as the primary key to handle your user ids.

If this is somehow going into production I'd suggest validating and sanitizing the data and use phps [password_hashing](http://php.net/manual/en/book.password.php) function on the password for obvious security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

First check your connection

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

If it's ok,  check your result

```
   if ($result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql)) {
                echo "I got the result yeah\n", mysqli_num_rows($result);
            }else{
               echo "No results buddy."
}
```